# SQl function in android

Tags: java, sql, android

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(rat) 
                               FROM "+ TABLE_NAME_EXTRA +" apkid=\""+apkid, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int somatotal = cursor.getInt(0);
```

I'm trying to do a SQL function like count and sum, but this code returns a exception saying "emptyvalues".

anyone know why?

Comment: Because there are no rows in the table?  Print out the actual query before it is run, and try running it outside of java/android to make sure it's doing what you intend.

Comment: aren't you missing a WHERE statement before the 'apkid'?

Comment: my bad.. its running well.. the exception it's in another side

Comment: Aren't you also missing a closing quote to match the one opened after `apkid=`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [DatabaseUtils.longForQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html) utility method to run the query on the db and return the value in the first column of the first row.

```
int sometotal=DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db,"SELECT COUNT(rat) 
                               FROM "+ TABLE_NAME_EXTRA +" where apkid=\""+apkid+"\"",null);
```